# res.cookie doesn't set any cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I was messing around with express and cookies. I used the cookie-parser example in the repository and `req.cookies` works perfectly, but when I try to use `res.cookie(name,value)` it doesn't set anything. It doesn't even give me an error.

Here's my code:

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('rememberme',1);
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
});

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: But you are aware that cookie values will only be available after the next request, right?

Comment: Yes I do, I request once to set the cookie and I request a second time to see the cookie. Both times gives me `{ }`

Comment: You don't actually send back a response.

Comment: @robertklep How do I send a response? On another route?

Comment: Use `res.end()` or `res.send()`.